# How to ignore/break all previous async calls, take only the last one?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I want to ignore/break all previous http calls if a new call started. E.g.:

```
data: string;

updateDataById(id: number) {
 this.http.get('url', {params: {id}}).subscribe(response => this.data = response);
}

ngOnInit() {
// First call, it will takes 3s, response will be 'cat'.
 this.updateDataById(8);

// Second call, but it will take only 1s, response will be 'dog'.
 this.updateDataById(46);
}
```

In this case data value will be 'dog' first time, then it will change to 'cat' later, because the first call's response time is longer than second call's response time.

How could data be a 'dog' first and last?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `switchMap` operator, but from your example I'm not sure how you're calling the change.  The gist of it:

```
// Start the "faster" request
of(fakeHttp()).pipe(
  // Switch to the this observable, cancelling the previous.
  switchMap(() => fakeHttp(true))
).subscribe(console.log); // 'cat' is never output


function fakeHttp(long = false) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log('Faking', long) // First outputs 'cat', then 'dog'
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(long ? 'dog' : 'cat')
    }, long ? 2000 : 200)
  })
}
```